# Ruby print statement is not dividing

Tags: ruby

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
percentage = 0
downloaded = 0
fileSize = 10000
while percentage <= 1
  downloaded += 1
  percentage = downloaded/fileSize
  sleep(0.1)
  print " Does not change: #{downloaded/fileSize}, Does not change: #{percentage}, Does change: #{downloaded}\r"
end
```

The `#{downloaded/fileSize}` and the `#{percentage}` does not change in the loop. Whilst the variable, `downloaded`, is actually changing in `#{downloaded}`. Why is `#{downloaded/fileSize}`, and `#{percentage}`, not changing in the print statement and how can I change this?

The "\r" makes it print on the same line, but removing it doesn't make the print statement work as expected.

Comment: I think it is doing integer division

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is doing integer maths it works with:

```
percentage = Float(0)
downloaded = Float(0)
fileSize = Float(10000)
```

Comment: You can also express a float with a literal by adding a decimal, eg: 0.0